# Configuration Changes to run BLAZEDS based Adobe flex application on Desktop

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

I am trying to run an adobe flex based application outside browser. Application is compiled using 'services-config.xml' file as parameter. In services-config.xml file the channels were configured as

```
    <channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.host}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
            <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
            <polling-interval-millis>0</polling-interval-millis>
            <wait-interval-millis>-1</wait-interval-millis>
            <max-waiting-poll-requests>0</max-waiting-poll-requests>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

and so on to pick host and port dynamically.

Now I have downloaded adobe_content_debugger.exe which allows me to run .swf file outside browser. However all the requests that are made to server go to http://localhost/contextRoot/messagebroker/amf. The {server.host} is picked up as localhost and {server.port} as empty value. Hence I cannot interact with backend server. How can we overcome this problem ?

Solutions I tried...
1) https://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/externalize_serviceconfig.html
This post asks you programatically create AMFChannel/channelset and add it to RemoteObject.

> ```
> var channel:AMFChannel = new AMFChannel("my-amf", amfEndpoint);
> channelSet.addChannel(channel);
> _serviceControl.channelSet = channelSet;
> _serviceControl.channelSet.addChannel(channel);
> ```

where _serviceControl is the remoteObject. But even after this the request is made to http://localhost/contextRoot/messagebroker/amf. I tried multiple combinations but only in vain.  Will programatically creating channelSet make settings comming from services-config file redundant ? services-config file refers other files like 'remoting-config.xml', 'proxy-config.xml', 'messaging-config.xml' which contains information on 'destinations'

Solution 2) 
Change services-config.xml as

```
    <channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://example.com/8556/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
            <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
            <polling-interval-millis>0</polling-interval-millis>
            <wait-interval-millis>-1</wait-interval-millis>
            <max-waiting-poll-requests>0</max-waiting-poll-requests>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

Then just map example.com to server IP in host file. This is a workaround but now the port is hard-coded and cannot be changed. Unless a proxy server is introduced.

Can someone help ?

Comment: If i try to add channel to existing channelSet instead of creating another channelSet, then it gives me an error 'Channels cannot be added to a ChannelSet that targets a configured destination'.  i.e. "_serviceControl.channelSet.addChannel(channel)" gives me above error.

Comment: If I do trace(_serviceControl.channelSet.channels[0].endpoint) then after programatically adding the channelSet to remoteObject, it gives me the url of my server aka 'amfEndpoint' mentioned above. But the calls are still made to localhost/context/messageBroker/amf